# large-scale regression in R with a sparse feature matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, regression

I'd like to do large-scale regression (linear/logistic) in R with many (e.g. 100k) features, where each example is relatively sparse in the feature space---e.g., ~1k non-zero features per example.

It seems like the [SparseM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SparseM/) package `slm` should do this, but I'm having difficulty converting from the `sparseMatrix` format to a `slm`-friendly format.

I have a numeric vector of labels `y` and a `sparseMatrix` of features `X` \in {0,1}. When I try

```
model <- slm(y ~ X)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ X) : 
invalid type (S4) for variable 'X'
```

presumably because `slm` wants a `SparseM` object instead of a `sparseMatrix`.

Is there an easy way to either a) populate a `SparseM` object directly or b) convert a `sparseMatrix` to a `SparseM` object? Or perhaps there's a better/simpler way to do this?

(I suppose I could explicitly code the solutions for linear regression using `X` and `y`, but it would be nice to have `slm` working.)

Comment: This looks very promising: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conferences/useR-International-R-User-2017-Conference/An-Efficient-Algorithm-for-Solving-Large-Fixed-Effects-OLS-Problems-with-Clustered-Standard-Error-Es on GH here https://github.com/DukeSynthProj/SyntheticDataXTXResources

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't know about `SparseM` but the `MatrixModels` package has an unexported `lm.fit.sparse` function that you can use. See `?MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse`. Here is an example:

Create the data:

```
y <- rnorm(30)
x <- factor(sample(letters, 30, replace=TRUE))
X <- as(x, "sparseMatrix")
class(X)
# [1] "dgCMatrix"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "Matrix"
dim(X)
# [1] 18 30
```

Run the regression:

```
MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse(t(X), y)
#  [1] -0.17499968 -0.89293312 -0.43585172  0.17233007 -0.11899582  0.56610302
#  [7]  1.19654666 -1.66783581 -0.28511569 -0.11859264 -0.04037503  0.04826549
# [13] -0.06039113 -0.46127034 -1.22106064 -0.48729092 -0.28524498  1.81681527
```

For comparison:

```
lm(y~x-1)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x - 1)
# 
# Coefficients:
#       xa        xb        xd        xe        xf        xg        xh        xj  
# -0.17500  -0.89293  -0.43585   0.17233  -0.11900   0.56610   1.19655  -1.66784  
#       xm        xq        xr        xt        xu        xv        xw        xx  
# -0.28512  -0.11859  -0.04038   0.04827  -0.06039  -0.46127  -1.22106  -0.48729  
#       xy        xz  
# -0.28524   1.81682
```

Comment: Strange to me to see use of an unexported function propounded as the accepted answer

Comment: Even an unexported function with a help page is strange!

Answer (score 17):

A belated answer: `glmnet` will also support sparse matrices and both of the regression models requested.  This can use the sparse matrices produced by the `Matrix` package.  I advise looking into regularized models via this package.  As sparse data often involves very sparse support for some variables, L1 regularization is useful for knocking these out of the model.  It's often safer than getting some very spurious parameter estimates for variables with very low support.

Answer (score 9):

`glmnet` is a good choice. Supports L1, L2 regularization for linear, logistic, and multinomial regression, among other options.

The only detail is it doesn't have a formula interface, so you have to create your model matrix. But here is where the gain is.

Here is a pseudo-example:

```
library(glmnet)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=4)

y_train <- class
x_train <- sparse.model.matrix(~ . -1, data=x_train)

# For example for logistic regression using L1 norm (lasso) 
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x=x_train, y=y_train, family='binomial', alpha=1, 
                    type.logistic="modified.Newton", type.measure = "auc",
                    nfolds=5, parallel=TRUE)

plot(cv.fit)
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean to write `x_train = ...(data = x_train)`?

Comment: Also worth noting that for those not trying to regularize, the advice here will be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405362/ordinary-least-squares-with-glmnet-and-lm

Answer (score 7):

You might also get some mileage by looking here:

- The [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html) package.
- The [High Performance and Parallel Computing R task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).
- A paper about [Sparse Model Matrices for Generalized Linear Models](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2010/abstracts/Maechler+Bates.pdf) (PDF), by Martin Machler and Douglas Bates from UseR 2010.

Comment: some slides are here, perhaps that was intended? https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2010/slides/Maechler+Bates.pdf