# Large-scale pseudoinverse

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, hpc

I would like to compute the [Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of an enormous matrix.  Ideally, I would like to do it on a matrix that has 23 million rows and 1000 columns, but if necessary I can reduce the number of rows to 4 million by only running on one part of my experiment.

Obviously, loading the matrix in to memory and running SVD on it is not going to work.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix_pseudoinverse) points to [Krylov subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace) methods and mention the [Arnoldi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration), [Lanczos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_iteration), [Conjugate gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient), [GMRES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMRES) (generalized minimum residual), BiCGSTAB (biconjugate gradient stabilized), QMR (quasi minimal residual), TFQMR (transpose-free QMR), and MINRES (minimal residual) methods as being among the best Krylov subspace methods.  But I don't know where to go from here.  Is computing the pseudoinverse of such a huge matrix even feasible?  If so, using which algorithms or software libraries?  I have a large computing cluster available, so parallel approaches are welcome.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169371/large-scale-regression-in-r-with-a-sparse-feature-matrix#3172815) points to the R package [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html).  Would that work?  Has anyone used it?  I normally work in Python, but don't mind using other languages and tools for this particular task.

Comment: Does the matrix have any special block structure?

Comment: @Joel: No, almost all elements are nonzero.

Comment: Is the pseudoinverse the end product or are you computing something with it?

Comment: @throwawayacct I am doing simple linear regression.  Let X be the matrix described above.  Let K be a matrix with the same number of rows as X but with ~100 columns.  I am trying to find a matrix T so that XT approximates K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off using a block iterative algorithm that converges directly to the least squares solution than computing the least squares solution through the pseudoinverse.  See "[Applied Iterative Methods](http://www.akpeters.com/product.asp?ProdCode=3424)" by Charlie Byrne.  These algorithms are closely related to the Krylov subspace methods, but are tuned for easy computation.  You can get an introduction by looking at chapter 3 of this [preprint of another](http://faculty.uml.edu/cbyrne/aclafctext.pdf) of his books.