# R weighted panel regression with random effect

Tags: r

Is there any way to estimate **random effect panel linear regression** in R using **weights** option?

For fixed effects, I can simply use

```
lm(y ~ x + factors(id_variable), weights=wgt)
```

However I am looking for RE as the number of individuals is too large and I hit memory limits.

Weighting is needed due to survey data type

If not available in R, is it available in **stata** or **SAS**?

Answer (score 2):

In my (limited) experience survey weighting for multilevel models is a can of worms (I mostly follow Andrew Gelman's opinion on this, e.g [this paper](http://stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/STS226.pdf) or [this blog post about it](http://andrewgelman.com/2012/07/26/some-thoughts-on-survey-weighting); here's an (unanswered) [CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89204/fitting-multilevel-models-to-complex-survey-data-in-r) on the topic). In other words, you might have to solve a statistical problem (what is the right way to handle this?) before you worry about the computational problem.

I do think Stata and/or SAS offer such capabilities (see CrossValidated link above), but I can't tell you much about them.

However, if you don't want/need random effects, i.e. you just want to handle a problem with a large number of fixed effects, you should be able to use a sparse model matrix as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169371/large-scale-regression-in-r-with-a-sparse-feature-matrix), as in the example below.

It will still be up to you to figure out how to deal with the weights.  I don't believe that the `weights=` argument in `lm`, `glm`, `lme4`, etc. handle survey weights. I believe the `survey` package is very sophisticated, but I don't know if its `surveyglm()` function can handle/has an option for sparse model matrices ...

```
library("Matrix")
library("MatrixModels")
set.seed(101)
ngrps <- 1e3
nobs <- 10
ntot <- nobs*ngrps
d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(ntot),
                x=rnorm(ntot),
                f=gl(ngrps,nobs))
object.size(X1 <- model.matrix(~x+f,data=d))  ## 80 MB
object.size(X2 <- sparse.model.matrix(~x+f,data=d))  ## 709K
system.time(m1 <- MatrixModels:::lm.fit.sparse(X2,d$y)) ## 0.004 seconds
system.time(m2 <- lm.fit(X1,d$y))  ## 9 seconds
```